# Optimise speed for hiding columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a short script for hiding columns in depending on cell values.

The script works but it is very slow and often Excel errors where the number of columns is large, for example > 200 columns.

```
Sub Bouton_hidingColumns()
Dim NumColonne As Integer

For NumColonne = Range("I11").Column To Range("IH11").Column Step 3
    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(11, NumColonne), Cells(119, NumColonne))) = 0 Then
         Columns(NumColonne).Resize(, 3).Hidden = True
    End If
Next NumColonne

End Sub
```

Example of script failure when the number of columns is high:
[image: Msgbox from Excel]

> Impossible de définir la propriété Hidden de la classe Range

(in English this is *Unable to set the hidden property of the range class*)

Can anyone suggest an solution? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what is the column number when you get that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing and then hiding in a single shot run okay for me

```
Sub OneWay()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("I11:IH119")
For Each rng2 In rng1.Columns
    If rng2.Column Mod 3 = 0 Then
       If Application.Sum(rng2) = 0 Then
          If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
              Set rng3 = Union(rng3, rng2.Resize(, 3))
          Else
               Set rng3 = rng2.Resize(, 3)
          End If
       End If
    End If
Next

If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then rng3.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveWindow.Visible = False` at the beginning of your script sometimes makes a big difference.

Make sure you put 
`ActiveWindow.Visible = True` on error catching.

Comment: I was providing a hint regarding the slowness of execution.